# Abstract factory with generics

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, factory-pattern

I have a pretty complex domain with various rules and exceptions and I wonder if the abstract factory may help me out of this jungle.

**Domain description**

There are various different hardware devices in a network. All of them have a IP address, but are either of type transmitter or receiver (which can change, depending on their configuration). How I access them (protocol) and how these access points look like depends on the device itself.

**Domain**

```
public abstract class NetworkDevice {

    public IPAddress IpAddress { get; set; }
    public List<Endpoint> Endpoints { get; set; }
    public NetworkConfiguration NetworkConfiguration { get; set; }

}

public abstract class Endpoint {

    public bool IsMulticast { get; set; }
    public string PayloadType { get; set; }

}

public IPCamera: NetworkDevice {

    // a IPCamera usually has various RTSP endpoints
    // Is the following solution acceptable v
    public List<RtspEndpoint> RtspEndpoints {
        get {
            return this.Endpoints.Where(x => x is RtspEndpoint);
        }
    }

}

public RtspEndpoint : Endpoint {

    public string MediaControl { get; set; }

}

public abstract SpecialDevice : NetworkDevice {

    // this device has RTSP and ONVIF endpoints
    // and can be EITHER transmitter or receiver
    // depending on configuration

}

public SpecialDeviceTransmitter : SpecialDevice {

    // has RTSP & ONVIF endpoints

}

public SpecialDeviceReceiver {

    // has only ONVIF endpoints

}
```

Now, I would like to create a new instance of a SpecialDeviceTransmitter that has a predefined set of 3 RTSP endpoints and 1 ONVIF endpoint. How can I make this without enums? And do I need a factory for every possible device and endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection to invoke constructors for different types. E.g. for every type you can create a constructor that accepts an array of endpoints and implement object creation like this:

```
    T CreateDevice<T>(params Endpoint[] endpts) where T: class
    {
        ConstructorInfo ctor = typeof(T).GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(Endpoint[]) });

        return ctor.Invoke(new object[] { endpts}) as T;

    }
```

Same pattern can be implemented for various types of `Endpoint` creation as well.
I omitted error checks here.

Answer (score 0):

For implementation details, your `SpecialDevice` class could have a bool value called `IsReceiver`, which will be set according to the configuration of the actual device. This assumes it can only ever be one of the two, however.

For the `EndPoint`s of your `SpecialDevice`, you could use a collection of `EndPoint`s, like you did with `IPCamera`. If you want to know what kind of endpoints your devices support you could use a `[Flags]` enum like so:

```
    [Flags]
    public enum EndpointFlags
    {
        Onvif = 0x10,
        Rtsp = 0x100,
    }
```

And call `HasFlag` to determine if your device supports a specific type of EndPoint.